# function calling ajax returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a javascript function which makes a JSON call to a web service using jQuery.
In the success function I need to evaluate the JSON response and if necessary make another call to a different method in the same web service.

Here is how I do it:

```
function firstAjaxCall(aid, tid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: "/webservices/Webservice.asmx/Method1",
        data: "{ auctionId: '" + aid + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var respData = response.d;
            //do some stuff
            if (respData.HasEnded == true) {
                clearInterval(tid);
                var end = false;
                end = endFunction(aid);
                if (end) {
                    // do some other stuff
                }
            }
        },
        failure: function (errorMsg) { alert(errorMsg.toString()); }
    });
}
```

and the endFunction which is being called from within the ajax success function:

```
function endFunction(aid) {
    var hasEnded = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: "/webservices/Webservice.asmx/Method2",
        data: "{ auctionId: '" + aid + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (callbackData) {
            var endRespData = callbackData.d;
            hasEnded = endRespData.Success;
            alert(hasEnded.toString());
        },
        failure: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown); 
        }
    });
    return hasEnded;
}
```

Here is the weird stuff. The ajax-call is made all right. The code on the server is running according to plan. However, if I try to set a firebug breakpoint in the success function of `endFunction(aid)` is is not hit, but the alert box is shown displaying the word true. This is somewhat good since it seems that we are actually reaching the success function. The `hasEnded` variable however is never set to true so it always returns false.
Calling `endFunction(1)` from the Firebug console displays an alert box with the word `true` and returns value `false`.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
It looks like you're using "failure" in the documentation you have "error":
error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
also you should do something like this:

```
function firstAjaxCall(aid, tid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: "/webservices/Webservice.asmx/Method1",
        data: "{ auctionId: '" + aid + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var respData = response.d;
            //do some stuff
            if (respData.HasEnded == true) {
                clearInterval(tid);
                var end = false;
                endFunction(aid,function(endv){
                  if (endv) {
                    // do some other stuff
                  }
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (errorMsg) { alert(errorMsg.toString()); }
    });
}

function endFunction(aid,endcallback) {
    var hasEnded = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: "/webservices/Webservice.asmx/Method2",
        data: "{ auctionId: '" + aid + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (callbackData) {
            var endRespData = callbackData.d;
            hasEnded = endRespData.Success;
            alert(hasEnded.toString());
            endcallback(hasEnded);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown); 
            endcallback("?");
        }
    });
    //return hasEnded;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers!
Tried the code above but when I run firstAjaxCall I get "endcallback is not a function". I think I need more guidance on this callback thing...

Comment: It should be something like that. I should perhaps remove the code and describe it more clearly.

Comment: Yes it should work this way, but somehow it doesn't...
I'm not asking you write the code for me, that would be too much to ask, but a little more help in getting the callback to work would be very helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: Doh! Sometimes I get surprised by my own stupidity. Of course the code above work!
Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is *asynchronous* — the `$.ajax` call will not wait for the server to reply.

Therefore, the `return hasEnded;` line runs before the AJAX callback.

You need to make your `endFunction` take a callback parameter, like `$.ajax` does.